# Question about conditional independence

Tags: probability-theory, independence

**Assumptions**

- Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables such that $Z$ is independent of
  $(X,Y)$.
- Let $h$ be a bivariate function such that $h(X,Z)$ is a random
  variable.

**Question**

Is $h(X,Z)$ conditionally independent of $Y$ given $X$?

**Attempt**

Let $A$ and $B$ be Borel sets. Let $x$ be a real number. Then $$P(h(X,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X=x)=P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X=x).$$ It remains to show that $$P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X=x)=P(h(x,Z)\in A\mid X=x)P(Y\in B\mid X=x).$$ I guess this equality follows from the  assumption that $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$. My reasoning: The assumption implies that $Z$ is independent of $Y$. This implies that $h(x,Z)$ and $Y$ are independent as $h(x,Z)$ is a function of $Z$ only. However, I am wondering if $h(x,Z)$ and $Y$ are also independent when we condition on the event $\{X=x\}$; and if so, why that is the case.

Maybe this argument works. $$\begin{align}P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X=x)&=\frac{P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B,X=x)}{P(X=x)}\\
&=\frac{P(h(x,Z)\in A)P(Y\in B,X=x)}{P(X=x)}\\
&=P(h(x,Z)\in A)\frac{P(Y\in B,X=x)}{P(X=x)}\\
&=P(h(x,Z)\in A\mid X)\frac{P(Y\in B,X=x)}{P(X=x)}\\
&=P(h(x,Z)\in A\mid X)P(Y\in B\mid X=x).\end{align}$$ This assumes that $P(X=x)>0$. What if $P(X=x)=0$? I guess I can make a similar derivation by looking at densities. Then my derivation would be, with integration over $\mathbb{R}^2$, $$\begin{align}P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X=x)&=\int1_{A}(h(x,z))1_B(y)f(z,y|x)dzdy\\
&=\cdots\\
&=\int1_{A}(h(x,z))1_B(y)f(z|x)f(y|x)dzdy\\
&=\int1_{A}(h(x,z))f(z|x)dz\int1_B(y)f(y|x)dy\\
&=P(h(x,Z)\in A\mid X)P(Y\in B\mid X=x).\end{align}$$ How can I provide a more general proof? Conditional distributions was what I found hard to understand when I read courses in measure-theoretic probability.

Comment: You would think the answer is yes, right? Can you put this in more formal language? Maybe use the definition of independence to write the conclusion and the premise of the result you have to prove? That would be a good start, because this theorem should be having a proof from definition. (If true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general proof can be obtained by the tower property of expectations. That is,
\begin{align*}
P(h(x,Z)\in A,Y\in B\mid X)&=\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{h(x,Z)\in A}\mathbf{1}_{Y\in B}\mid Y,X]\mid X]\\
&=\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{Y\in B}\mathrm{E}[\mathbf{1}_{h(x,Z)\in A}]\mid X]\\
&=P(h(x,Z)\in A)P(Y\in B\mid X).
\end{align*}
Now, the connection between $\mathrm{E}[\,\cdot\mid X]$ and $\mathrm{E}[\,\cdot\mid X=x]$ allows us to conclude the above also holds when conditioning on $X=x$.